# How to correctly shrink the bullets of itemize

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, itemize

How can I shrink the bullets of `itemize` without change its positioning and the centering versus the items? My code below show that behaviour in fact the two item underneath have a bullet shifted down respect the other two above...

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny$\bullet$}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can raise the bullet to your liking. The following does that (to the extreme):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setbox1=\hbox{$\bullet$}\setbox2=\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}
\setlength{\mylen}{\dimexpr0.5\ht1-0.5\ht2}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny$\bullet$}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{\mylen}{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

On the left is the default `$\bullet$`. The middle shows `\tiny$bullet$` while the last shows a raised `\tiny$\bullet$` to exactly the same vertical height as it should be for `$\bullet$`. However, as mentioned, this is a bit extreme. You could avoid all the length calculations and just use `\raisebox{0.25ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}` which yields a comparable positioning.

I would also suggest using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which allows you to obtain a similar output using

```
\begin{itemize}[label=\raisebox{0.25ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}]
  %...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Why did not you put \relax after \ht2?

Comment: @FormlessCloud This is not necessary inside `\setlength`

Comment: @Werner, can you phrase your answer also in terms of `\setdefaultitem`?

Comment: @einpoklum: And what is `\setdefaultitem`?

Comment: @Werner: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that: the `paralist` package's `\setdefaultitem`.

Answer (score 34):

using `\tiny` shifts the math axis so the vertical alignment of the bullet, so what you want is not a smaller font but a smaller symbol in the same font set (or to raise the symbol by hand)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\cdot$}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}


\renewcommand\labelitemi{{\boldmath$\cdot$}}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer too, but I chose the other because I can simply use the LaTeX's font size commands to chose how big make the bullets : )

Answer (score 28):

The smaller symbol can be centered around the original math axis via `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer in my opinion.

Comment: Nice answer. But I would suggest to use `\scriptsize` instead of `\tiny` because this will give a bullet that has the same size as a `\textbullet` with the `lmodern` package.