# Getting an Itemize Error

Tags: itemize

I'm getting a few errors here: Undefined control sequence, Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted), and Missing number, treated as zero.

Did I not include a necessary argument which caused a syntax error?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{\mylen}{\tiny$\bullet$}} %Reduces bullet size

\begin{document} 

Consider the set $A = \{1, \{2, 3\}, 4, 5\}$. The following statements are true about A.

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item $1\in A$
\item $2 \notin A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \in A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \not \subseteq A$
\item $ \{\{2, 3\}\} \subseteq A$
\item $ \emptyset \subseteq A $
\item $ \emptyset \notin A $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Errors]

Comment: The code snippet that you have provided runs absolutely fine when a `\documentclass` and `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` are added, meaning your problem is outside of this small code snippet. Please provide a full [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Please, make a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the correctly pasted error messages (then they will tell, which commands are undefined).

Comment: the error message should be fairly clear you have used `\mylen`  without defining this length so in `\raisebox{\mylen}` it can not raise the bullet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of your error message tells you what your problem is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mylen 

l.12 \item $
            1\in A$
?
```

You have used the control sequence `\mylen` but you have not defined it anywhere.

If I replace `\mylen` with some value, let's say `0.5ex`, although I have no idea what kind of effect you're going for, all is well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}}

\begin{document} 

Consider the set $A = \{1, \{2, 3\}, 4, 5\}$. The following statements
are true about A.

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
  \item $1\in A$
  \item $2 \notin A$
  \item $ \{2, 3\} \in A$
  \item $ \{2, 3\} \not \subseteq A$
  \item $ \{\{2, 3\}\} \subseteq A$
  \item $ \emptyset \subseteq A $
  \item $ \emptyset \notin A $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Feel free to substitute a different value, or you can define `\mylen` to be some value if you want:

```
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{0.5ex}
```

This will enable the original definition, which I suppose you borrowed from somewhere

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\raisebox{\mylen}{\tiny$\bullet$}}
```

To work fine.

However, for best results, you should follow the instructions in this Q & A:

[How to correctly shrink the bullets of itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119319/how-to-correctly-shrink-the-bullets-of-itemize)

Which I would imagine is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

### [Version 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/372004/1) of the question

The snippet works out of the box with standard LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $1\in A$
\item $2 \notin A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \in A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \not \subseteq A$
\item $ \{\{2, 3\}\} \subseteq A$
\item $ \emptyset \subseteq A $
\item $ \emptyset \notin A $
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### [Version 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/372004/2) of the question

The length `\mylen` is undefined, see David Carlisle's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372004/getting-an-itemize-error#comment919062_372004) and Au101's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372012/16967).

The raising of the smaller bullet to the original math axis can be done without the length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$%
}

\begin{document}

Consider the set $A = \{1, \{2, 3\}, 4, 5\}$.
The following statements are true about A.

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item $1\in A$
\item $2 \notin A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \in A$
\item $ \{2, 3\} \not \subseteq A$
\item $ \{\{2, 3\}\} \subseteq A$
\item $ \emptyset \subseteq A $
\item $ \emptyset \notin A $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]