# How to resize \textbullet without the bullet moving down?

Tags: graphics, symbols

I would like to separate words in a word list with a midpoint. However, the dot printed by \textbullet seems a bit too big for me, and \textperiodcentered{} a bit too small.

I came across a solution with the package \usepackage{fix-cm}. However, `\scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet}`shifts the bullet vertically down, which is not wanted.

This is the main.tex I work with:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}

Word1 \scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet} Word2 \scalebox{0.5}{\textbullet} Word3

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to reduce the size of `\textbullet` or enlarge the size of `\textperiodcentered` while keeping the symbol vetically centered?

Comment: You could do `\textbf{\textperiodcentered}`. But see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119319/82917.

Comment: Awesome, exactly the right size in my view. Many thanks @campa!

Comment: Do you mind if I mark this question as duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: Isn't the linked answer just valid within an itemize-environment, meaning for bullets of a vertically aligned enumeration? However, with your solution, I have the right bullet size to horizontally separate words, without changing the "itemize-environment"-bullet-size. Should I be wrong, you can surely mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

We need to guess the sidebearings of the bullet, so we can determine the geometric center thereof.

This is font dependent, so I provide a macro for the factor by which to reduce the width and a method for determining it visually.

I also provide an example with the standard bullet next to the scaled one and to `\textbf{\textperiodcentered}` with the standard Computer Modern fonts and with NewTX (that seems to require the same factor).

I also provide a macro for the scaling factor, because different fonts might require different scalings and provide an example again with NewTX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}

\newcommand{\textsmallbulletfactor}{0.825}% font dependent
\newcommand{\textsmallbulletscale}{0.5}% font dependent
\newcommand{\textsmallbullet}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{\textbullet}%
  % how much the bullet stays above the baseline
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0-\textsmallbulletfactor\wd0\relax
  \dimen2=\dimexpr(\ht0+\dimen0)/2\relax % the height of the center
  % scale the bullet sitting on the baseline
  \sbox0{\scalebox{\textsmallbulletscale}{\raisebox{-\dimen0}{\textbullet}}}%
  % now we raise it
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dimen2-0.5\ht0\relax}{\usebox0}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

% let's check whether 0.825 is good
\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{\textbullet} \framebox[0.825\width]{\textbullet}
\endgroup

X \textbullet\textsmallbullet\textbf{\textperiodcentered}

\end{document}
```

#### Output with Computer Modern

[image]

#### Output with NewTX

[image]

You see that `\textperiodcentered` is out of place here.

#### Output with NewTX and scaling factor 0.6

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below: (it was originally suggest by the great `egreg`)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallbullet}{} % for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand\smallbullet{%
  \mathord{\mathpalette\smallbullet@{0.75}}%
}
\newcommand{\smallbullet@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

And you should use `\smallbullet` instead of `\textbullet`

Comment: Note that you misspelled `\makeatother`. Furthermore, the intended usage seems to be within text, and this will fail in such a situation.

Comment: @campa typo was fixed, thanks for pointed out...